# Running custom Docker container with GPU using Vertex AI Pipelines - how to install NVIDIA driver?

Tags: nvidia, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I need to run a custom Docker container with GPU support using Vertex AI Pipelines, and I'm not seeing a clear way to do that. This requires several components:

1. Applications (pytorch in my case)
2. CUDA toolkit
3. CUDA driver
4. NVIDIA GPUs

I can use a [NVIDIA Docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) base image for #1 and #2, and a GCP accelerator for #4, but how do I install the CUDA driver in a Vertex AI pipeline? There's documentation on how to install NVIDIA drivers [on GCE instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu#no-secure-boot) and [GKE nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#installing_drivers), but nothing for Vertex AI.

One option could be to [create a derivative container based on a GCP Deep Learning Container](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-containers/docs/derivative-container), but then I have to use a GCP container and don't have as much control over the environment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can use one of the pre-built GPU docker containers:

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/pre-built-containers

Comment: Or, specify the CUDA base in your DOCKERFILE:  FROM nvidia/cuda:11.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu18.04